# expectation of a function of two dependent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have a formula that I believe it's right but I do not know how to prove it. Could you please give me some arguments or references to show that.

Let $\{X_t,t\geq0\}$ be a gamma process. Let $\tau_M$ be the hitting time of the threshold $M$ and $X_{\tau_M}$ be the associated level. Note that $X_{\tau_M}\geq M$ because gamma process is a jump process. The formula to prove is that:

For any $\varphi$ measurable and non negative,
$$
\mathbb{E}[\varphi(\tau_M,X_{\tau_M})]=\mathbb{E}[\sum_{t\geq0}\varphi(t,X_{t^-}+\Delta X_t)\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{t^-}<M\}}\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{t^-}+\Delta X_t\geq M\}}]
$$
A figure explaining the notations $X_{t^-}$ and $\Delta X_t$ can be found at this link 
http://s11.postimage.org/gmi5xjiib/fig.png

Thank you so much for your help!

Tuan

Comment: What is the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This integrates an almost sure identity valid for every nondecreasing step process. Namely, fix some nondecreasing step function $f:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R$ and let $t_M=\inf\{t\geqslant0\mid f(t)\geqslant M\}$. Then,
$$
t_M=t\iff f(t^-)\lt M\leqslant f(t^-)+\Delta f(t),
$$
and then $f(t_M)=f(t^-)+\Delta f(t)$, hence
$$
\varphi(t_M,f(t_M))=\sum_{t\geqslant0}\varphi(t,f(t^-)+\Delta f(t))\,\mathbf 1_{f(t^-)\lt M\leqslant f(t^-)+\Delta f(t)}
$$
**Edit:** Consider for example the function $f$ defined by $f(t)=1$ if $0\leqslant t\lt3$ and $f(t)=5$ if $t\geqslant3$, and assume that $M=2$. Then $t_M=3$ and there is exactly one value of $t$ such that $f(t^-)\lt M\leqslant f(t^-)+\Delta f(t)$, which is $t=3$. Furthermore, for $t=3$, $f(t^-)=1$, $\Delta f(t)=4$, and $f(t)=5$.

Thus, $\varphi(t_M,f(t_M))=\varphi(3,5)$ and the sum of the series in the RHS is $\varphi(t,f(t^-)+\Delta f(t))$ for $t=t_M=3$, that is, $\varphi(3,1+4)=\varphi(3,5)$.

Comment: Hi Did, many thanks for your answer! But I stil do not understand why $\varphi(t_M,f(t_M)) = \sum_{t\geq O}\varphi(t,f(t^-)+\Delta f(t)) \mathbf{1}_{f(t^-)<M\leq f(t^-)+\Delta f(t)}$. Can you please explain it or just give me some references about it. Thank you again.

Comment: There is only one nonzero term in the sum over $t\geqslant0$. Identifying it might provide you an explanation of the identity in my post. If it does not, please say so.

Comment: Sorry, but I stil do not understand. Maybe a reference is better to me!?

Comment: I am not sure you tried what I suggested in my last comment. Anyway, see Edit.

Comment: OK, it's clear now to me. Thank you so much!